# How to remove a specific value/rows from an inner map of an outer map in Guava Multi Map

Tags: java, mapping, guava, multimap

I wanted to remove specific keys from my inner multimap **"car_model_id"** that has a char value **'Y'** contained from the **DetailClass**'s instance variable **"flag"** by querying via the outer maps key.

```
   // Outermap:
   Multimap<Long, Multimap<Integer, DetailClass>> car_manufacturer_id = ArrayListMultimap.create();

   // Innermap:
   Multimap<Integer, DetailClass> car_model_id = ArrayListMultimap.create();

   // DetailClass instance variables
   attr_key, serial, flag, state

   // Inserting Values to Inner Map
    car_model_id.put(1, new DetailClass(1016,'PO-90','Y',"TX"));
    car_model_id.put(1, new DetailClass(1011,'PO-90','N',"TX"));
    car_model_id.put(1, new DetailClass(1022,'PO-90','Y',"LA"));

    car_model_id.put(2, new DetailClass(1016,'PO-80','Y',"RE"));
    car_model_id.put(2, new DetailClass(1011,'PO-80','N',"GA"));
    car_model_id.put(2, new DetailClass(1022,'PO-80','N',"NY"));

   car_manufacturer_id.put((long) 501747, car_model_id);
```

Comment: a multimap of multimaps is almost certainly taking things too far!

Comment: well the data is complicated from the very beginning. needed a dual duplicate key holder mapping system.

Comment: So you want to remove all **values** from the inner multimaps if the flag is 'Y'?

Comment: @DanielBickler: Yes!

Comment: Would you be willing to consider changing your datastructures? Or maybe using a composite key?

Comment: yes what else do u suggest?

Comment: There is a syntax error.  This is neither a string nor a character `'PO-90'`.  Perhaps you meant `"PO-90"`

Comment: yes its a just a string. typing mistake. sorry! @Enwired